# Compare dates using javascript engine

Tags: java, date, compare

I am using Javascript engine to compare values. Values can be double or date. (strings)

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
// Date value is populated dynamically here
engine.eval("dateValue = " + "01/02/2012");
// The condition is populated dynamically here
if ((Boolean) engine.eval("dateValue <=" + "12/31/2012")) { 
  System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

The above code works fine with double values, but gives wrong results with dates. For the above example it should display TRUE, but it displays FALSE. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
engine.eval("var dateValue = " + "new Date(2012, 02, 01);");
...
if ((Boolean) "dateValue <=" + " new Date(2012, 12, 31);")
```

In your script 12/31/2012 will be interpreted as a mathematical expression.

another possibility for the test you wanna do is something like:

```
engine.eval("var test = dateValue <=" + " new Date(2012, 12, 31);")
Object myBoolean = engine.get("test");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it threw an Exception Exception in thread "main" com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1

Comment: otherwise you could assign this value to a variable and get the value of the variable through the engine object.